# Find the network card mac address in Windows

Tags: windows-7, mac-address

How can I find the network card mac address in Windows (7)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it applies to any windows.

1. Open command window:  [Win] + R,
   type CMD  - press Enter
2. Type ipconfig /all

You will see all required info.

Answer (score 13):

why not just try:

```
getmac /v
```

KISS Principal at play!

Comment: This is a much better solution than anything here.

Comment: Indeed it is and I forgot all about that. We have had some problems using that in scripts before which is why we tend to use another method, but I think that was dodgy scripting rather than anything serious.

Comment: Works really well compared to the other solutions, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We use the MAC address in combination with Wake On Lan methods to power on machines remotely for updates etc etc.

Because no one thought to get MAC addresses before rolling out machines and we have no auto asset DB it was going to be a bit of a slow process to gather all the MAC addresses.

So I wrote this simple line that goes in the login script

```
ipconfig /all | find /i "physical address" > \\server\share\%computername%.txt
```

This will enter the mac address of the current logging in machine to a file in a shared area with the filename set as the computer name. Obviously you can use this how you want but is a nice method of collecting data.

Comment: I think you need something a bit more robust that just this. Often there are multiple network cards on a computer, each with their own mac address (WiFi, Ethernet, Bluetooth, ...) so in this case all are listed, even if they are not active.

Answer (score 1):

Click start,

Click 'RUN'

In the box that appears type CMD and click 'OK'
In the black window that appears on screen type

```
ipconfig /all
```

Hit return

Information about all of your network adapters will be returned. The MAC address is listes as 'Physical Address'

Type

```
exit
```

and hit return to end the session

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a GUI method,

1. Open Network Connections (in Control Panel)
2. Double-click your connection icon (e.g. Local Area Connection) - or right click and choose Status
3. Click the Support tab
4. Click the Details button

The MAC address is listed as the Physical Address in this window.